# How to cath the drop event AFTER the node drop?

Tags: extjs6

[How to fires event after Drag & Drop on TreePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305822/how-to-fires-event-after-drag-drop-on-treepanel)

[On an ExtJS drag and drop tree using the drop or beforedrop listeners dont seem to fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458359/on-an-extjs-drag-and-drop-tree-using-the-drop-or-beforedrop-listeners-dont-seem)

[How do I make an ExtJS drag and drop tree be copy only -- not remove items from the display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125482/how-do-i-make-an-extjs-drag-and-drop-tree-be-copy-only-not-remove-items-from)

I'm trying to take the new parent of the moved node:

```
    drop: function (node, data, overModel, dropPosition) {
        var theNode = data.records[0];


        console.log( theNode.data.parentId );
        console.log( theNode.parentNode.id );

    },
```

but :

note 1: the `node` parameter is not the real TreeNode, just a HTML tag.

note 2: The `theNode.parentNode` is not updated and I'm taking the old node parent (before the drag). It will be updated AFTER the `drop` function.

How can I take the new node parent?

Comment: sort of afterdrop?

Comment: I think a defer is the only one solution, never seen about afterdrop function, i completely started to hate sencha's drag and drop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved (ExtJS 6.2.x).

```
drop: function (node, data, overModel, dropPosition) {
    var thisIsTheMovedNode = data.records[0];
    var thisIsTheNewParentNodeData = overModel.data;
    var thisIsTheOldParentNodeData = data.records[0].parentNode;
}
```

The new parent node ID is : `overModel.data.id`;